# annulus connected radially is homotopic to a constant curve

Tags: complex-analysis

Homotopy of Two Curves
Let D ⊂ C be a domain.

Let C = C(φ1 : [0, 1] → D) and C
′ = C
′
(φ2 : [0, 1] → D)
be
curves with

φ1(0) = φ2(0), φ1(1) = φ2(1).

We say that φ1 and φ2 are homotopic in D if there exists a continuous map

Φ : [0, 1]×[0, 1] →
D

satisfying
(i) Φ(0, s) = φ1(0) = φ2(0), ∀s ∈ [0, 1].

(ii) Φ(1, s) = φ1(1) = φ2(1), ∀s ∈ [0, 1].

(iii) Φ(t, 0) = φ1(t), Φ(t, 1) = φ2(t), ∀t ∈ [0, 1].

Such map Φ is called a homotopy connecting φ1 and φs.

[enter link description here](https://ibb.co/GsFYzbP)
Now i want to show that curve in the picture is homotopic to a constant curve. 
I haven't studied homotopic topic much except for whatever is there in Conway till where i have read.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: It looks fine now? Thank you for the help

Comment: Can someone answer it. Or any hint....